# Create worksheets based on multiple filters

Tags: excel, vba

I found and am using the following code and works great for what it is intended, but for my purpose i need to be able to provide more than just 1 filter before creating the sheets.

```
'https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-filter-value-then-copy-data-to-new-worksheet/

Public Sub FilterThenCopy()
   Dim ws, newWS, currentWS As Worksheet
   targetCol = 1   'define which column you want to break
   Dim objDict As Variant
   Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   Set currentWS = ActiveSheet
   'Add unique value in targetCol to the dictionary
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, targetCol).End(xlUp).Row
     If Not objDict.exists(Cells(r, targetCol).Value) Then
       objDict.Add Cells(r, targetCol).Value, Cells(r, targetCol).Value
     End If
   Next r

  If currentWS.AutoFilterMode = True Then
     currentWS.UsedRange.AutoFilter
  End If
  currentWS.UsedRange.AutoFilter
  For Each k In objDict.Keys
    currentWS.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=objDict.Item(k)
   'delete worksheet if worksheet of item(k) exist
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      If wsExists(objDict.Item(k)) Then
        Sheets(objDict.Item(k)).Delete
      End If
    Next ws
   'crate worksheet using item(k) name
    Set newWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    newWS.Name = objDict.Item(k)
    'copy filtered contents to new worksheet
    currentWS.Cells.Copy
    newWS.Range("A1").Select
    Sheets(objDict.Item(k)).Paste
  Next k
  currentWS.Activate
  currentWS.AutoFilterMode = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function wsExists(wksName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   wsExists = CBool(Len(Worksheets(wksName).Name) > 0)
   On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

If i record a macro to set multiple filters, this is what is recorded

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$13").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Daniel"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$13").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="0078"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$13").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="661"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$13").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0007"
```

Im trying to figure out how i can make this work. The first 3 criterias needs to be dynamic as it is now and produce a sheet for each unique value combindation. But the 3 will need to be either dynamic as well(95% sure it needs to be) or a way that it can be provided at execution time. Because of the way they work, may need to be able to provide a way to allow the user to select how they want the sheets created based on the fields they pick, if not then default would be to created based on the 3 criteria.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this ask..

Here is the test data im working with and the expected tabs based on unique combination of Dept, Class and Sub

[image: Test Data and Expected Results]

Comment: Are you trying to concat the data?

Comment: no, i have a master set of records on 1 sheet, we manually filter that data down to 4 criteria's and for each set we save that filtered data into a new tab, we then transfer those individual sheets to other departments templates as needed. Current the manual filtering into new sheets is taking a long time depending on the master data. So we are trying to at least speed up that process by autofiltering based on unique values in the 4 columns.

Comment: Use the advance filter function if you want multiple criteria in multiple columns

Comment: in my above sample data, i would need a tab for each unique value in column A. Keep in mind that all that is already working in the VBA code provided above, i just need help modifying the code to also include additional criteria before creating each tab.

Comment: new tabs are created using colA but the filter needs to dynamic on colB-D?

Comment: In the above example i would expect to end up with 12 tabs, because there is only 1 unique record for each of the 4 columns. And is this example, i would need to tweak the sheetname logic to create a unique name with a combo of the column values so each tab is different.

Comment: Ill need to reach out to my manager and see, maybe we can create a tab for each unique ColA and ColB values which would then bring it back down to 6 tabs..

Answer (score 0):

You could use another dictionary like `objDict` with values from column B and then loop over both dicts to make the filters. The worksheet names could be a concatenation of the values from both dicts e.g "Daniel-0078" or "Daniel-0079" so you can compare and delete them if necessary. You could also use this reasoning to make the twelve tabs you wanted (using four different dictionaries) but also consider that the maximum length for worksheet names is 30.

Comment: ok, so got a little more clarification of how i need to filter and create the new worksheets.  Ill update the above original post with new pictures and description. But basically i need to be able to filter, the filtered lists until i get to a final level of data and then create the sheet. thank you for the suggestions and lets see if i can still use them in the new order of things.